# ImageResizer with Azure Blob storage Azurewebsites

Tags: azure, imageresizer

I'm looking to resize an image that is uploaded to my site, I'm using Azure Blob storage to store the physical files and I'm serving the files either via a public container or a private container (depending on the image).

I found the following tutorial the describes ImageResizer (http://benfoster.io/blog/high-performance-image-processing-with-image-resizer-and-azure). However, it is requesting for the container to be public. In my scenario I have multiple containers (public and private - blob). I place sensitive images in the private container, and I have my own api to download from the container if the user has access to view the image.

In this scenario can I use ImageResizer ?

Is it possible pre-save the images in various sizes as opposed to doing this in real time ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ImageResizer's Azure blob storage provider works with both public and private containers.

https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/azurereader2

Comment: Hi I had read that document, and I read the walk through from Ben Forster. The document doesn't indicate, unless I've missed something that it will work with Private Containers (or privacy on the Blob) . In Ben's walkthrough I noticed the following statement "From the portal create a container to store your images. Note that the access is set to Public Blob. If no querystring modifiers are provided the Azure Reader plugin will automatically redirect to the Azure blob URL.". I was concerned, based on this statement, that it would have to be a public container.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible pre-save the images in various sizes as opposed to
>   doing this in real time ?

Yes. It is possible, we are currently doing just that using [Event Grid subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview)

Based on the examples in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event) we have an Azure function that is triggered by a BLOB being written that generates 3 different sizes of image.

I personally found that `ImageResizer` used with Azure Storage simply wasn't fast enough and whilst performance may improve with caching/CDN we needed the first request to be fast so generating the smaller images at the time of writing them worked much better for us.